# What is network URI in google cloud rest API

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to create router via the rest-api.

according to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/routers) i need to supply network URI to router, but the problem is that I do not understand what is the URI of the network (when i try to supply just the network name I receive malformed URI error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URI looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/development-123456/global/networks/default
```

Use the following command to list your networks:

```
gcloud compute networks list
```

Once you know the name of your network (example `default`) use this command to list details which includes the `selflink` field which is what you need:

```
gcloud compute networks describe default
```

Note: I am not sure if the router requires the network or a subnetwork. The above commands provide both types of information.